# How to shift the CSS animation from the first column to the second column?

Tags: css

I was checking the CSS code for an animation I found: [The code](https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/qwrmwE)

The animation takes the first column of the background and animate by looping through the background from top to bottom (the left side of the background).

The problem however is that I couldn't replicate the process for the other 3 types of movement( The other 3 columns).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .tuna {
      animation: walk-cycle 1s steps(12) infinite;
      background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-90/tuna_sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
      height: 200px;
      width: 400px;
      margin: 100px auto 0;
    }
    
    @keyframes walk-cycle {
      0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
      }
      100% {
        background-position: 0 -2391px;
      }
    }
    
    html {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="tuna"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I divided the height and width of the image and shifted the start of the animation from the second column but no matter what height or width I add to the animation, it simply doesn't work.

```
@keyframes walk-cycle {  
  0% {background-position: 400 0; } 
  100% {background-position: 400 -2391px; } 
}
```

I thought the problem might be in the "0 0" value in the background property as they stand for the default background position ( the top-left corner) but no matter how many times I change it's value, it simply doesn't work, it only give me an empty page.

```
background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-90/tuna_sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
```

I tried to search for the " 0 0" value but couldn't what value they stand for.

Comment: what are the "3 other types of movement" ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif The background is big image with multiple  columns, each column is a few frames for a specific movement. the first column used in the animation is for the walking,etc. The BG URL: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-90/tuna_sprite.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the generic code based on your PNG. All you need to do is to update the variables

```css
.tuna {
  --s: 100px; /* height of the image */
  --n: 12; /* number of frames */
  --i: 0; /* the movement (0,1,2,3) */

  height: var(--s); /* define only the height */
  aspect-ratio: 2; /* you need a width = 2*height */
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-90/tuna_sprite.png);
  background-size: 400% auto; /* we have 4 columns so width = 4*100% and we keep the height auto */
  background-position: calc(var(--i)*100%/3) 0;
  animation: walk-cycle 1s steps(var(--n)) infinite;
}

@keyframes walk-cycle {
  100% {
    background-position: calc(var(--i)*100%/3) calc(-1*var(--n)*var(--s));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tuna"></div>
<div class="tuna" style="--i:1;--n:6"></div>
<div class="tuna" style="--i:2;--n:12"></div>
<div class="tuna" style="--i:3;--n:13"></div>
```

Comment: That does let me shift the animation as I please but I  still couldn't figure what was wrong in the code I mentioned, why couldn't I simply shift the animation despite shifting the starting position and I still don't know what the " 0 0 " stands for.

Comment: @GloriousChaos you were missing the unit after `400` and you need a negative offset to shift with pixel values. I am giving you a better approach using percentage so you can easily scale it

Comment: Yup, that's what I was missing, I added the "px" unit and made it negative and it worked just fine, also the " 0 0" was indeed the background position, I just had to insert the unit and the negative to make it work.